# Tool to check DNS records from multiple nameservers?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

Is there a desktop or online tool that will query multiple name servers (dozens ideally) to get an idea if and how a DNS record change is propagating?

I know of many free tools, but they only check one name server.  I'm thinking something more along the lines of the awesome namebench utility.

Maybe I don't understand it well enough, but I get frustrated sometimes after making changes and not knowing if they are propagating properly.

Comment: Be sure to set the TTL to the time you want it to take to propogate everywhere ahead of time.  If somebody asks the dns server for a result, and the TTL has expired, the dns server should check again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Online tool -> http://www.whatsmydns.net

Comment: Awesome just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I like check-host.  Here's example.com data:

http://check-host.net/check-dns?host=example.com

Comment: Note, whatsmydns.net has the option for IPV6 too if you select AAAA records, hadn't really noticed before